# As an API creator, should I hide client API keys once they've been created?

Tags: api, api-key

I'm working on an API where a user of my API can sign up for my API to get an API key. When I generate this API key, I'm using asymmetric encryption to create a hash that I store in my database.

My question I have is this, once the user generates an API key and then signs out, the next time they sign in, I don't have the API key anymore to display in my app's dashboard. Is this normal / acceptable?

Do other APIs do it differently? i.e. do they offer the API key to the user? and if so, are they storing the unhashed API key in the DB? Is this a balance between user experience and security?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In OAuth2, it's pretty common for systems to show the OAuth2 client id at all times, but the OAuth2 secret exactly once.

If you want to make the user experience good, focus on making it easy to roll a fresh API key without expiring old ones. You can show a list of API keys (not the secret), and when they are last used so it's also easy to let the user disable keys that are likely out of use.

Comment: thanks for clarifying. I think hiding the client secret but showing the api key to the end user makes a lot of sense from a UX perspective.

To clarify, that does mean that I will be storing the API keys in plain text in my DB, and the security comes from the client's password. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, api client ids in OAuth2 are like usernames, and client secrets are like passwords.

Answer (score 0):

API Keys are not usually considered secure. Typically API Keys are visible to the clients. API keys should not be used to perform secure authorization. However, you can design any system as you want and in your current design if a third-party or attacker can make successful invocations to your API by obtaining the so called "API Key", it's better to hide it and let the user take the responsibility to securely store the key in somewhere else. Also you should make sure in your API, there must be a way to

1. Revoke an existing API key.
2. Generate a new API key with an expiry date.